# NestJS + GraphQL - optional data in @InputType (code first)

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I would like to make some data I send in graphql mutation **optional** but **not** nullable. I'm using the code-first approach.

For example:

```
@InputType()
export class CreateUserDto {
  @Field()
  firstName?: string;
}
```

I understand I can use the `nullable` parameter or possibly `defaultValue` but none of these options are really usable in my case.

Also, I know there is the Nest's `PartialType` utility but that would mean creating another file with the class if I'm correct and that doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 6):

set nullable to true
in @Field decorator like:

@Field({ nullable: true })

So your code should be:

```
@InputType()
export class CreateUserDto {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  firstName?: string;
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me! I tried with the @isOptional decorator but it seems to be useless

Answer (score -1):

`use isOptional() validators`

This will help you.

Comment: This will not set a field as optional in graphql argument, it will just tell class-validator to ignore the validators if the value is null